# how to delete facebook cookies when we sign in through facebook

Tags: jakarta-ee, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie, cookiestore

I have provided one social auth link in my website ,my problem is if i logged in through facebook and logged out from my application but still facebook's `c_user` cookie is there .How to delete cookie from other domain,because it keeps track of the user.I am using java.

Comment: you can see this in stackoverflow website itself.

Comment: More elaborate answers and possible semi-solutions can be found [in this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828221/cant-logout-of-my-facebook-oauth-session-without-logging-user-out-of-facebook)

Answer (score 3):

Situation: A feature on your website allows visitors to log in using their Facebook account. When the user logs out of your application, the `c_user` cookie from Facebook still exists in your user's browser after being set by Facebook.

Problem: You don't want Facebook to continue tracking your users' movements with it's `c_user` cookie after they have logged out.

Solution: Due to the web browsers and cookies work it's impossible for your website to control what cookies Facebook places in your user's web browser. The best you can do is to tell your users to clear their browser's `c_user` cookie.

Comment: Is it right to tell your users to clear the cookies? Yes and no. Most people will ignore it so it's of limited benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Redirect the WebBrowser to `facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: What clarification is implied here?

Answer (score 0):

"How to delete cookie from other domain?".

You can not delete a cookie from another domain. Not without a huge security hole.

Could you explain why you even want to do this? What kind of problems does this cookie cause?

Comment: this cookie tracks the facebook user session,even u logout from original application it keeps the fb user logged in.