# Removing facebook pixel cookies with JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've implemented the facebook pixel widget using NuxtJS, however I believe this question should be agnostic.

In order to comply with GDPR, I'm allowing my users to opt out of facebook pixels tracking. Stopping the tracking works fine, but for some reason I can't delete the actual cookies. I tried various methods for removing them using my plugin, or manually using document.cookie. Unfortunately I receive no error messages from the console, so I really can't tell what's going on. This is on localhost on a development server.

For example, I tried this:

```
document.cookie = "wd=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=facebook.com"
```

My workaround so far as to use location.reload() as the cookies seem to be sessionbased (even though the expiry says otherwise for some)
Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: “*for some reason I can't delete the actual cookies.*” You can’t interact with cookies that belong to other domains. Possible duplicate of [how to delete facebook cookies when we sign in through facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501101/how-to-delete-facebook-cookies-when-we-sign-in-through-facebook)

Comment: Why not making the opposite: putting the cookie as opt-in rather than removing it at opt-out?

Comment: @esqew so if the user clicks my cookie banner > opts out of facebook, there is no way to forcibly remove those cookies without a reload?
Edit: I read the other post & that somewhat explains it, I guess a reload is the best I can do then.

Comment: @kissu They are never set unless they user accepts the cookie policy or the cookies individually.